# iPhone 5S network query

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 5S cellular network has ceased working. The iPhone is 3.5 years old and has been consistently reliable.  The battery is also working well.  I have tried the usual troubleshooting methods to restart the network, but none have worked.  I can used my mobile on WiFi and the Apps such as Facebook, WhatsApp and Viber still.   How can I recover the carrier cellular network?

Comment: By network do you mean wi-fi or cellular?

Comment: @JMY1000 - given that she says WiFi works, it's a safe bet the issue is the cellular network.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that a problem has developed with the LTE Modem portion of your iPhone (orange box).  It's a hardware issue.

[image: iPhone 5S logic board]

You'll want to do a factory reset to see if it fixes it.  However, in my experience with symptoms like this, the only thing you can possibly do is take it in for service to a facility that specializes in this type of repair.